# image not saving on django models

Tags: python, django, forms, image, django-cms

I created an album with a photos as foreign key but somehow when i add a photo it does not save probably in my database or admin site

Here are my models:

```
class AlbumPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
     name            = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                   help_text=_('e.g: Zuerich city, or Zuerich Hoengg'))
     slug            = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), blank=True, null=True, unique=True, db_index=True)
     description     = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)    
     cover_photo     = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Add cover photo'), null=True, blank=True)
     is_active       = models.BooleanField(_('active'), blank=True)
     date_created    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     date_modified   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     sort            = models.IntegerField(_("Sort Order"), null=True, blank=True, default=0)

     def __str__(self):
         if self.name:
            return u"File for %s" % self.name
         else:
            return u"%s" % self.name

      def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/album_detail%i/" % self.id

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['sort']
         verbose_name = "Album"
         verbose_name_plural = "Albums"


class Photo(models.Model):
     photo = models.ForeignKey(AlbumPluginModel, verbose_name=_('choose album'), null=True, blank=True)
     image1 = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Photo'), null=True, blank=True, upload_to="/static/img/")                              
     sort = models.IntegerField(_("Sort Order"), null=True, blank=True, default=0)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.image1

    def __str__(self):
       return u"%s" % self.image1

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['sort']
         verbose_name = _("photo")
         verbose_name_plural = _("Photos")
```

forms.py

```
class AlbumPluginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AlbumPluginModel
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'cover_photo', 'is_active',]


    class PhotoPluginForm(forms.ModelForm):
        photo = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='select album',aqueryset=AlbumPluginModel.objects.all(), required=False)

        class Meta:
            model = Photo
            fields = ('photo', 'image1', )
```

views.py

```
 def add_photo(request, id=None, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':

         all_photos = Photo.objects.all
         form = PhotoPluginForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'photo': id})
         template_name = 'photo_create.html'

         context = {
            "form": form,
            "all_photos": all_photos,
    }

         if form.is_valid():

            all_photos = form.save(commit=False),
            form.save()

            messages.success(request, "Photo was added.")
            return redirect('/photos')
        else:
            print("error: form nicht valid")

     return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` in the template?

Comment: You should save it in media folder. Not in static folder. `/static/img/` should be `/media/img/`

Comment: @MounaDhaouadi just did not saving

Comment: @MHassan also did but still not saving

Comment: Are you facing problem in saving `cover_photo` of `AlbumPluginModel` or `image1` of `Photo`?

Comment: @MHassan having problems with both cover_photo and image1

Comment: check my asnwer

Comment: @MHassan i did it like this:     

    cover_photo     = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Add cover photo'), null=True, blank=True, upload_to="/media/img/")

still not saving

Comment: Kindly see updated answer.

Comment: @M Hassan 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 0):

You should add `upload_to` parameter for field in which you want to upload some file in server. In your case, in `AlbumPluginModel` your `cover_photo` will be

```
cover_photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Add cover photo'), null=True, blank=True, upload_to='path_where_you_want_to_save')
```

If you call `save()` with `commit=False`, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. In this case, it’s up to you to call `save()` on the resulting model instance. You should change your view like this

```
all_photos = form.save(commit=False),
all_photos.save()
```

Comment: @M Hassan 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 0):

after a long try i finally found the answer:

in views.py
i chnaged this line from

```
form = PhotoPluginForm(request.POST or None)
```

to:

```
form = PhotoPluginForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

and in my template i forgot this:

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```